# Android App Development | Custom BaseAdapter not working

Tags: android

I am making a planner app, with the same tasks every week. I first used an ArrayAdapter to show all tasks of the selected day, but then I decided to make my own Adapter. I've never made one so I looked on the internet and then made my mine by mostly copy-pasting and changing the variables. When I add a task in the EditActivity, you can see it but when you switch the selected day and come back or if you go to the DisplayActivity, it's gone. There's no error. I also tried implementing Filterable, but I also don't know what it is so I mostly copy-pasted.

**TaskAdapter**

```
public class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter /*implements Filterable*/ {
private HashMap<Task, ViewHolder> holders = new HashMap<>();
private List<Task> mData = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public TaskAdapter(Context context, List<Task> tasks) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mData = tasks;
    holders = new HashMap<>();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        if (holders.containsKey(task))
            return;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holders.put(task, holder);
    }
}

public void addItem(final Task task) {
    mData.add(task);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (holders.containsKey(task))
        return;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    holders.put(task, holder);
}

public void removeItem(final Task task) {
    mData.remove(task);
    holders.remove(task);
}

public void setItem(int position, Task task) {
    mData.set(position, task);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Task getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).getTask());
    return convertView;
}

public TextView getTextView(Task task) {
    return holders.get(task).textView;
}

/*
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            mData = (List<Task>) results.values;
            TaskAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            List<Task> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            results.values = filteredResults;

            return results;
        }
    };
} */

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

}

**EditActivity - onCreate()**

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        selectedDay = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DAY");

        List<Task> tasks = getTasks(selectedDay);
        tasks.add(new Task(this, getIntent().getExtras().getString("TASK_NAME"), false, true));
        setTasks(selectedDay, tasks);
        updateList(tasks);
    }
```

**EditActivity - setTasks(String day)**

```
    private void setTasks(String day, List<Task> tasks) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(day + ".dat", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(tasks);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EditActivity - updateList()**

```
    private void updateList(List<Task> tasks) {
    if (tasks.size() == 0) {
        noPlanTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        noPlanTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, tasks);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_edit);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I only pasted the code I thought was important / useful. If you want any more please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: how does edit activity and display activity interact? I currently don't have the full picture how your app works, but it seems you create a new instance of adapter every time you update list, you should just do `adapter.addItem();` then `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` or something to that effect

Comment: what do you need `HashMap<Task, ViewHolder> holders` for? seems you should use `ArrayAdapter` if you are new to this

Comment: @JonathanDarryl I was creating a new instance every time. I'm now going to make a global variable instead.

Comment: @pskink It's so I can get the ViewHolder & TextView by giving the Task. I need this so I can strike through the textview when the task is completed.

Comment: all you need to do is to update your data model inside your adapter and call `Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()`, no need for any map of holders